# Always connection failed when performing a login

Tags: c#, mysql

it is my first time using mysql in Visual Studio 2019. When performing a connection test it is connection but when i create simple login form it always show connnection failed and i can't figure out the problem please help me...

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(@"Data Source=localhost;port=3306;Initial Catalog=Payroll_Management;User Id=root;password=;");
    private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void label3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void textBox3_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int i = 0;
        
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            MySqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
            MySqlDataReader reader = null;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM `user` Where UserName '" + User.Text + "' and Full_Name = '" + Fname.Text + "' and Password = '" + Pass.Text + "'";
            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            MessageBox.Show("Please Try Again:");
            if (reader.Read())
            {
                DashBoard Db = new DashBoard();
                Db.Show();
                this.Close();
                MessageBox.Show("Login success:");
            }

            conn.Close();
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Connection failed:");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [C# MySql example](https://zetcode.com/csharp/mysql/). Also, when you get into something new, you better google/research it before straightly asking a question. *This is my first time using MySql in Visual Studio*
what kind of question is this? You mean with C#, not Visual Studio. And, using MySql with C# is quite similar to Sql. So, the question doesn't stand

Comment: You need to get it to report the real exception, not just your made-up message. A lot of things happen inside that `try` block, it's not a guarantee that the connection is the problem. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/try-catch

Comment: P.S. This code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks - please learn how to use parameters in order to mitigate that, and also you need to hash the passwords, don't store plain text passwords in your database.

Comment: _Always connection failed_ it's because you are getting an error and you didn't know it so  it always says `"Connection failed"`

Comment: You can't figure out the error because as I already mentioned you **aren't checking for the real error, you're just outputting an invented one**. Read the Microsoft docs articles I linked you to which shows how to use a try/catch properly to report the exception instead of discarding/ignoring it. Once you get the real exception details you'll have a better chance of understanding what's really going on and fixing it. P.s. I don't know what research/learning you've done about try/catch previously but whatever you learned from seems to have taught you badly.

Answer (score 1):

I think is the syntax error , just change `"SELECT * FROM user Where UserName '" + User.Text + "` to `"SELECT * FROM user Where UserName = '" + User.Text + "`. Probably you missed a (=) so it throws a Sql Syntax exception and get connection failed.